# User CPU time deviation. What is it caused by?

Tags: performance, time, process, cpu

I am wondering why the time command in Unix always outputs different user CPU time. It is said it is time that CPU spends executing user code of the needed process, so it excludes tasks that are managed by the kernel:

- Any I/O or other hardware waits and interrupts, also cache management
- Other processes' intervention (taking control away)
- All things that user code does not know about

But for a simple C program with bubble-sorting of 1000000 elements it always shows user CPU time ranging from 0.3 to 1.0 seconds.

I have found little information about that in classic books about kernels and operation systems. Please, enlighten me, somebody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'All things that user code doesn't know about`

is not true. User time means CPU cycle used by user mode. 
There are 2 execution modes, **user mode** (with limited privileges) and **kernel mode** (with almost all privileges). In user mode generally operations not involving higher level privileges are performed. User mode is switched to kernel mode whenever kernel call/system calls are made.

More information on CPU modes is available here,

1. http://www.linfo.org/kernel_mode.html
2. http://minnie.tuhs.org/CompArch/Lectures/week05.html

Thus even for simple bubble sort program you will use quite a CPU cycles. Measuring user time in real seconds per program can be difficult as well as less useful because getting exact numbers won't make much sense. This will depend and vary a lot on underlying HW, Kernel versions, other processes sharing resources etc. It varies even in consecutive runs - range can be considered in such cases.

In general cases, User CPU time will be higher than System CPU time but inverse is possible.

Comment: Thanks, I know about kernel and user modes and switching. My question was more about causes of huge deviation, because I consider that everything beyond user code is kernel mode and it is accessed via system calls like read/write with C front-end functions. Btw, is it more useful to measure code performance with CPU cycle count?

Comment: Yes. That will be a good measure but again dependent on HW and software versions. But good for benchmarking.